# Sequelize require models/index.js in main app and pass down or require in module files

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In my node/express app that uses Sequelize, I am requiring the models/index.js file (all the db models) in the main app file and then passing it down to the modules/functions that service the various API endpoints. I'm unclear whether this is the correct way to handle this or whether I should simply require the models/index.js in each of the various modules that utilize Sequelize. My concern is that by including it in each of the individual modules I would be creating multiple sets of connection pools to the DB server. By passing it down to functions from the app level, I have a single shared instance. Any ideas what's best?

Comment: If models/index.js exports an object that contains models then importing it in different places you'll get the same object.

Comment: Thanks, that's super helpful. Does this happen because of the way node handles required files or is in the way Sequelize is designed?

Comment: Because of the way node handles required files. You still can turn an object returned by index.js into a function (like a constructor) where you can create a new sequelize object with its own connections and registered models if you wish independent sequelize connections and models at each place you do require('.models/index.js')